# How do I change the color of the checkbox to a gradient in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, checkbox

I'm trying to implement a beautiful CheckBox with a gradient color in a flutter
Tell me, is there a way to somehow specify Linear Gradient instead of active color without messing with the Container color?

[image: my checkbox code]

CheckBox code:

```
ValueListenableBuilder CheckSex(ValueNotifier<String?> sexNotifier) {
  return ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: sexNotifier,
    builder: (context, pickedSex, child) {
      return Row(
        children: ["Мужской", "Женский", "Другой"].map((String sex) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              Text(sex),
              Checkbox(
                activeColor: Colors.indigo[500],
                value: sex == pickedSex,
                onChanged: (pick) {
                  sexNotifier.value = sex;
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a restricted widget (CheckedBox) try creating your own widget where you can create a container and use a gradient color, like the code written below :

```
   bool switch = true;

InkWell(
onTap: () {
  switch = !switch;
},
child: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment(0.8, 1),
        colors: switch? [
          Color(0xff1f005c),
          Color(0xff5b0060),
          Color(0xff870160),
          Color(0xffac255e),
          Color(0xffca485c),
          Color(0xffe16b5c),
          Color(0xfff39060),
          Color(0xffffb56b),
        ] : Colors. white, // Gradient from https://learnui.design/tools/gradient-generator.html
        tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I don't understand how to make the container change its contents when clicked, maybe you could tell me how to write this code?

Comment: Simply create a bool for color and tap toggle it. LIke, I have update the code above.